# R 3d plot of distance matrix with colored points

Tags: r, plot

I've plotted a distance matrix in R using `scatterplot3d`, and would now like to assign a unique color to every single point. For instance, in the following example, the plot would contain five points (**A-E**):

```
       A       B       C       D       E 
A      0      0.1     0.2     0.1     0.2
B     0.1      0      0.1     0.2     0.1
C     0.2     0.1      0      0.1     0.2
D     0.1     0.2     0.1      0      0.1
E     0.2     0.1     0.2     0.1      0
```

At present, my `scatterplot3d` code for the appearance of the points is very simple:

```
s3d <- scatterplot3d(x,y,z, main="Just A Test", pch = 19)
```

How do I go about making each of the points appear a different color (using hex codes)?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the `color` argument in `?scatterplot3d` .... ?

```
dd <- read.table(header=TRUE,text="
       A       B       C       D       E 
A      0      0.1     0.2     0.1     0.2
B     0.1      0      0.1     0.2     0.1
C     0.2     0.1      0      0.1     0.2
D     0.1     0.2     0.1      0      0.1
E     0.2     0.1     0.2     0.1      0")
```

Here I'm assuming you want to use columns A-C as your coordinates ...

```
library(scatterplot3d)
## some made-up colors
cols <- c("#000000","#fa0ace","#eeabce","#5a0af0","#883856")
s3d <- with(dd,scatterplot3d(A,B,C, 
    main="Just A Test", pch = 19, color=cols,cex.symbols=3))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the response! I did take a look at the `color` argument, but the problem is that my actual matrix has a few hundred different rows, divided between about a dozen different colors. Is there any way of incorporating vectors into the code, to make the groupings easier? For example, #000000 for rows 1-15, #fa0ace for rows 16-30, and so on.

Comment: `newcols <- rep(original_colors,each=15)`.  (I'm confused; your question says you want "each point" to be a different color ... This is why a *reproducible example* is a good idea ...)